# Query appears to timeout on MySQL/Sequelize intermittently

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this query which appears to timeout intermittently

```
SELECT l.date, p.type
FROM (SELECT "2019-01-22T20:45:00" AS date UNION SELECT "2019-01-29T07:15:00" AS date) l
INNER JOIN pinfare_peak p
ON l.date BETWEEN p.start AND p.end;
```

Is there something wrong with it? When I try this query on MySQL workbench it seems consistenly ok. But on Sequelize, it seem to result in:

```
TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out
at ResourceRequest._fireTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:62:17)
at Timeout.bound (/var/task/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:8:15)
at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
```

On RDS error logs, I do see things like:

```
Aborted connection 10 to db: 'income' user: 'income' host: '10.0.13.26' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

But I am not sure if they are related

## Update

My code looks like:

```
const sqlList = dates.map(date => {
  return `SELECT "${date}" AS date`
}).join(' UNION ')
const sql = `
  SELECT l.date, p.type
  FROM (${sqlList}) l
  INNER JOIN pinfare_peak p
  ON l.date BETWEEN p.start AND p.end
`
console.log('Query', sql.replace('\s+', ' '), new Date())
let results
try {
  results = await sequelize.query(sql, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
} catch (err) {
  console.log('FAIL TO QUERY DB', err.message)
  throw err
}
```

It fails the the DB select. When I use the same select query generated on MySQL workbench on the same DB, it works fine. And not slow actually. Why does it cause a timeout on Node?

Comment: Can you please add node code also.

Comment: @PrayagC.Patel added node code